# How to force Hive to distribute data equally among different reducers?

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, reducers

Imagine I want to send the Iris dataset, that I have as a Hive table, to different reducers in order to run the same task in parallel on R. I can execute my R script through the transform function and use lateral view explode on hive to do a cartesian product on the iris dataset and an array containing my "partition" variable, like on the query below:

```
    set source_table = iris;

    set x_column_names = "sepallenght|sepalwidth|petallength|petalwidth";
    set y_column_name = "species";
    set output_dir = "/r_output";
    set model_name ="paralelism_test";    
    set param_var = params;
    set param_array = array(1,2,3);

    set mapreduce.job.reduces=3;

    select transform(id, sepallenght, sepalwidth, petallength, petalwidth, species, ${hiveconf:param_var})
    using 'controlScript script.R ${hiveconf:x_column_names}${hiveconf:y_column_name}${hiveconf:output_dir}${hiveconf:model_name}${hiveconf:param_var}'
    as (script_result string)
    from 
    (select * 
    from ${hiveconf:source_table} 
    lateral view explode ( ${hiveconf:param_array} ) temp_table 
    as ${hiveconf:param_var}
    distribute by ${hiveconf:param_var}
    ) data_query;
```

I call a memory control script, so please ignore it for the sake of objectivity.
 What my script.R returns are a list of the unique parameters it has received (the "params" column populated with the "param_var" array values) and the number of rows the partition it gets has, as follows:

```
    #The aim of this script is to validate the paralel computation of R scripts through Hive.

compute_model <- function(data){
  paste("parameter ",unique(data[ncol(data)]), ", " , nrow(data), "lines")
}

main <- function(args){

  #Reading the input parameters
  #These inputs were passed along the transform's "using" clause, on Hive.
  x_column_names <- as.character(unlist(strsplit(gsub(' ','',args[1]),'\\|')))
  y_column_name <- as.character(args[2])
  target_dir <- as.character(args[3])
  model_name <- as.character(args[4])
  param_var_name <- as.character(args[5])

  #Reading the data table
  f <- file("stdin")
  open(f)
  data <- tryCatch({
    as.data.frame (
      read.table(f, header=FALSE, sep='\t', stringsAsFactors = T, dec='.')
    )}, 
    warning = function(w) cat(w),
    error = function(e) stop(e),
    finally = close(f)
  )

  #Computes the model. Here, the model can be any computation.
  instance_result <- as.character(compute_model(data))

  #writes the result to "stdout" separated by '\t'. This output must be a data frame where
  #each column represents a Hive Table column.
  write.table(instance_result,
              quote = FALSE,
              row.names = FALSE,
              col.names = FALSE,
              sep = "\t",
              dec='.'
  )
}

#Main code
###############################################################

main(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE))
```

What I want hive to do is replicate the Iris dataset equally among these reducers. It works fine when i put sequential values on my param_array variable, but for values like array(10, 100, 1000, 10000) and mapreduce.job.reduces=4, or array(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5) and mapreduce.job.reduces=11, some reducers won't receive any data, and others will receive more than one key.

**The question is: is there a way to make sure hive distributes each partition to a different reducer?**

Did I make myself clear?
It may look silly to do it, but I want to run grid search on Hadoop and have some restrictions on using other technologies that are more suitable to this task.

Thank you!

Comment: In short, you want Hive to read all your data once, compute elaborate statistics on your custom key, generate a clever plan to scatter the keys fairly among the reducers -- i.e. all rows for the same key go to the same reducer, but all reducers get roughly the  same number of rows -- then read the data a second time to do the scattering? What's the point? If you are dealing with **Big** data, then the two-pass process is too expensive, it's probably cheaper to allocate extra containers so that even if some remain idle the processing goes "fast enough"...

Comment: Well, not really. As I understand it, Hive will generate mappers to read the data, as you described, and then compute the statistics on the reducers. All I want is to send each key to a different reducer. It won't read the data again, got it?

Comment: AFAIK the query plan is done at **compile time**, based on HDFS file/split size and cardinality estimates. No dynamic stats between mmapper and reducer steps. Anyway, the first reducer may start as soon as the first mapper has finished, and that first reducer may have finished well before the last mapper has finished *(imagine a skewed data set where the largest mapper fails and has to restart...)*